# State-of-the art factor models for intraday event studies

Tags: factor-models, high-frequency, intraday, event-study, abnormal-returns

I want to do intraday event studies. For this purpose, I have stock data on a 15 minutes interval.

What is/are currently the state-of-the art factor model(s) for calculating intraday (ab)normal returns?

Whould it be also reasonable to factor models such as the one-factor model, Fama & French three-factor model or the Carhart four-factor model?